# Docker's value and scenarios in native Windows environment

Tags: docker, windows, dotnet

AFAIK, typically Windows enterprise stack components are quite monolitic services, like Windows IIS and MS SQL Server. Still, there are "Windows containers".

- Are they indeed runnable in containers and this makes sense?
- Are there other Windows native containerization scenarios?

In [this example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server) Microsoft refers to a ".NET-nanoserver" image. The [base image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-samples/~/dockerfile/) is there a ".NET runtime" - I consider this is something else than an OS base image.

Answer (score 2):

> Are they indeed runnable in containers and this makes sense?

According to this [documentation](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/windows/windows-containers/README.md) it is possible to run windows in docker. Yes it could make sense as this would be comparable to the positive effects of running linux in docker. [Note that](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#getting-started-with-windows-containers):

> Disclaimer: This lab is still in work, and is based off of the blog,
>   but you can test and leverage the example walkthroughs now, if you
>   want to start experimenting. Please check back as the lab evolves.

Whether it makes sense: From a Linux perspective it does not as a Windows container will be significantly larger than a Linux one at the moment. From a Windows perspective it does not make sense as well as Windows itself is not as lightweight at the moment as Linux. Imagine that one runs 50 war files on a dedicated Windows server at the moment. If one would use Windows Docker containers for that purpose then a dedicated server should be used as a base image, each war file should be run in a separate container. This means that the number of required resource would grow exponentially. I assume that the creators of the native Windows Docker container take this into account and that this issue will be solved in the future.

---

> Are there other Windows native containerization scenarios?

What is the definition of a microservice? One could also argue that running SQLServer and IIS are microservices if one compares it with running IIS and SQLServer and other Windows services on a Windows server instead of separately. If one compares it with running Linux in docker then one could use a windows server as a base image by defining `FROM windows` in a dockerfile and run tomcat in a Windows container instead of running it on a dedicated server.